# Vim beginner: Can't find my source file after compilation and closing program

Tags: c, vim

I wrote a program in VIM on linux. I compiled and ran it by typing ":!gcc -o hw % && ./hw.c". After closing vim and coming back, my ".C" file is now a big mess of weird characters(mostly @) and stuff which I assume means that it's an executable but.. the problem is, I can't see my source code anymore. What really happened? Where can I find my source code? Is it lost forever?

Comment: It sounds like you made `gcc` compile your source code to a file with the same name as the file with said source code, which would overwrite your source file.

Comment: If you really typed `:!gcc -o hw % && ./hw.c` and the file you were editing was `hw.c`, then (a) the compilation should have done no damage, and (b) the run of `./hw.c` should have failed; you want to run `./hw` which you just created, not the source code you compiled it from.  However, if you somehow got it wrong, the chances are that you are hosed; the source is probably lost forever, unless you were using a VCS to manage it (in which case you can recover from the last version in the VCS, but any changes made since then are probably lost).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it lost forever

If it looks like this:

[image: Binary python]
Then pretty much yeah. It seems you compiled the source code and output the binary in the original source file.

If you want my advice, don't execute gcc from inside vim. Resort from using commands like this: `:!gcc -o hw % && ./hw.c`. Always save `:w` (and perhaps exit) and then compile from the shell.

Comment: Yeah it's like this :s

I'll do it from the shell from now on. Thanks!

Comment: @user2997154 In the future, another preventive measure against situations like this is the use of revision control software, such as mercurial and git..